# Show hidden scrollbar

Tags: javascript

A client is opening our website into a popup window using JavaScript with window.open. They are turning off scrollbars and making the window a fixed height, causing the pages to not be scrollable. I control the code of the website being loaded this way, but not the calling JavaScript. Is there any way I can force the display of scrollbars?

Answer (score 1):

```
body { overflow: auto }
```

should bring back the scroll bars. If it doesn't, and the `scrollbar` directive in fact turns off the body's scroll bars (I don't know right now whether that is the case), add a wrapper DIV in the body:

```
html, body { height: 100% }

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto

}


<div class="wrapper"> ......
```